# Making File Writable and Readable in Python

Tags: python

I am making a find and replace script to fix some stuff on my website. I am using Python 3.3.2.

Here is my code:

```
import re

f = open('random.html', 'w')

strToSearch = " "

for line in f:
    strToSearch += line

patFinder1 = re.compile('<td>Sermon Title</td>\
            <td><audio preload="none" controls src="http://www.orlandobiblechurch.org/Audio/\d{6}ldm.mp3"></audio>\
            </td>\
        </tr>')

findPat1 = re.search(patFinder1, strToSearch)

findPat1 = re.findall(patFinder1, strToSearch)

for i in findPat1:
    print(i)

subFound = patFinder1.sub('<td>Lord\'s Day Morning</td>\
            <td><audio preload="none" controls src="http://www.orlandobiblechurch.org/Audio/\d{6}ldm.mp3"></audio>\
            </td>\
        </tr>', strToSearch)
print(subFound)

f.write(subFound)
f.close()
```

The problem is that python tells me that the file is not readable. If I changes this f = open('random.html', 'w') to f = open('random.html', 'r') to this, it says it is not writable. It makes sense why it needs both, but if I put both in, it tells me there must be exactly one read/write thing. I am positive that this is something basic, I just can't figure it out. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried "w+"? I found this with a quick search: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f = open('random.html', 'r+')

Source: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `r+` or `w+` as the second parameter to open it in both modes. Refer to [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Also, have you considered using a `with` statement? They are more pythonic:

```
with open('random.html', 'w+') as f:
    do_stuff()
```

This has a great advantage that you don't need to manually do `.close()` afterwards.

- `strToSearch` can also be re-written as `strToSearch = ''.join(f.readlines())`
- Have you considered using a HTML parser such as [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for stuff like this? Better and easier than regex :)

Comment: Hmm, Beautiful Soup looks interesting, but all the documentation talks about installing it on Ubuntu. I assume that I would simply click on the setup.py, right?

Comment: @DogLover You can, yes. Or a simple `pip install bs4` :)